# Facebook application redirect inside an iFrama

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have an issue with one of my facebook apps.
Right now I'm writing a game application which should run in a tab in my fan page.
The flow of the process is:
The user lands in the tab inside the fan page --> authorizes the app --> starts playing
I want EVERYTHING to run inside the iFrame in the tab fan page.
The thing is, once the user confirms the application permission, I'm using a redirect Javascript function

```
    $url = "game.php";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">top.location.href='".$url."'</script>";
```

to redirect the user to the game, BUT the redirection causes the flow to leave the fan page and the tab.

How can I leave the user inside the iFrame to play the game?

Thanks!

Comment: you know top.location.href redirect the parent window. so remove the top from the top.location.href and then try it.

Comment: @munjal Even though its a simple mistake the user has done, consider posting that as an answer so that future visitors knows this as answered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you know top.location.href redirect the parent window. so remove the top from the top.location.href and then try it.